# How save user login and password in app

Tags: objective-c, macos, save, nstextfield, autologin

I am new to objective-c. I've already made authorization window, using AFNetworking sent a POST request to the server.
How can I make saving the login and password if the user wants. What would you every time a program is loaded, the user needs to press enter.
What tool make this is?
Here is the screenshot :

[image]

Comment: [Use the keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Keychain** is a good way to store private data like password and username. 
Search google as "Using Keychain to Store Username and Password"